# Adding ArcGIS Online Services to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online

Looking for info on how to add web mapping services from the Ohio Department of Natural Resources website to QGIS.  I've tried nearly a dozen different things online and still can't get results.  Don't normally ask for help in places like this, but decided to attempt this route for fear that it was impossible (permissions issues, etc.). Link to data I want to add is posted below:

https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/arcgis/rest/services/OIT_Services/odnr_landbase/MapServer

Comment: What version of QGIS?

Comment: Ive followed these instructions to attempt to add the Qld Govt Veg Management Map Server, however I receive a 'parser' error and no details can be retrieved. [Here is the URL](http://qldspatial.information.qld.gov.au/catalogue/custom/search.page?q=%22Queensland%20vegetation%20management%20web%20map%20service%22).

Comment: How do I access arcgis mapserver if it required a login username / password? I tried the basic login using the username/password; but it gave me an error 499

Answer (score 25, accepted):

QGIS 2.16 / 2.18 / 3.00:

1. Layer - Add Layer - Add ArcGIS FeatureServer Layer...
2. New (for a new connection). Give a name and enter https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/arcgis/rest/services/OIT_Services/odnr_landbase/MapServer/ in field URL.
3. Connect (connect to service to fetch layers).
4. Select layer. For example Current Township.
5. Add.

QGIS 2.14:

1. Install ArcGIS REST API Connector plugin.
   (a. Plugins - Manage and install plugins...
   b. Tab Settings.
   c. Mark checkbox Show also experimental plugins.
   d. Tab All.
   e. Search for ArcGIS, select and install ArcGIS REST API Connector plugin.)
2. Hit the ArcGIS icon in the Manage Layers Toolbar.
3. Enter the layer URL in field Layer URL. https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/arcgis/rest/services/OIT_Services/odnr_landbase/MapServer/2 Layernumber is important!
4. Put cursor in field Layer Name. If Layer URL is correct Layer Name will show up.
5. Connect to add features to QGIS.

---

When I checked the data, not all layers worked well.

- Counties: QGIS 2.16.0 gave me a crash. FME failed, log
  said No resultsPython Exception : fmeobjects.FMEGeometry
  or None is required FME said 0 features. The same layer in the V3 service did work and gave me 164 features.
- Historic_Township: 1365 features
- Current_Township: 1330 features
- Land_Subdivision: QGIS 2.16.0 gave me a crash. FME failed, log said No resultsPython Exception : fmeobjects.FMEGeometry or None
  is required. FME said 29917 features.
- Statewide_Parcels: QGIS 2.16.0 gave me a crash. FME failed, log said Encountered an unexpected error. The error code from the server was '500' and the message was: 'Error performing query operation'. Details: ''

Comment: Thanks!  Your post didn't completely answer my question (I got the same error as you), but it DEFINITELY filled in the gap so I could figure it out. This particular layer is only loading with the plugin for 2.14 and you have to select the box where it only pulls the shapes within view.  THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 5):

With QGIS 2.18 there are huge improvements in connecting to an ArcGIS Server map service.  Use the Layer > Add Layer > Add ArcGIS MapServer Layer.. command.  I just blogged about this yesterday.  The complete steps are:

1. Copy the URL of the map service.  The URL must end with "/MapServer":  https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/arcgis/rest/services/OIT_Services/odnr_landbase/MapServer
2. Open QGIS
3. Go to Layer > Add Layer > Add ArcGIS MapServer Layer..
4. In the Dialog box click the "New" button
5. In the "Create a new ArcGISMapServer connection" window enter the name "ODNR Landbase" and paste the URL from Step 1 into the URL field and click the "OK" button
6. Click the "Connect" button and the layers from the map service will be displayed
7. Select/highlight the layers in the list that you want to ad to your QGIS project and click the "Add" button

For another example with illustrations using a different ArcGIS Server visit my blog - http://geobern.blogspot.ca/2017/03/using-geonb-map-services-in-qgis.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called **Add ArcGIS Map Server Layer**. To get the tool just find menu Layer >>  Add Layer >> Add ArcGIS Map Server Layer... See the tutorial [How to use ArcGIS REST API Service in QGIS](http://www.geodose.com/2017/08/how-to-use-arcgis-rest-api-service-qgis.html)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on GIS.StackExchange. https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4642/should-link-only-answers-be-flagged-as-not-an-answer-on-this-site