# Using ArcGIS Tile service in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online-basemaps

Im trying to load a tile service in my QGIS 2.8 map canvas.
Talking about the following service: https://tiles4.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Dijkenkaart_van_Nederland/MapServer

Ive tried several methods but nothing seems to work.
As you can see by clicking the link, there are json, api and tile urls.

There must be a way to make this service useful?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  It would be really great if you could expand on what other methods you've tried.

Comment: I've tried TileLayer, but it doesnt seem to work. Also tried several methods to get a WMS out of it. But thusfar no result. Also tried using the json script but I dont have the knowlegde to import that to a good file.

Comment: ArcGIS map- and featureservices are available out of the box since 2.16. A plugin existed earlier but not sure from what version? Maybe 2.10?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202615/adding-arcgis-online-services-to-qgis/202633#202633

Comment: @buddiebubba the plugin seems to work only with WFS, it does not like the tiled service.

Comment: Yup. @DouweVermeer should upgrade to 2.16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me this way:

`Layer -> Add Layer -> Add ARCGIS MapServer Layer`

Click on `New`

Provide a name, like `Dijkenkaart`

For URL, Paste the URL you gave in your question.

Then Click on `Connect` and `Add`, and you should see the server data:

[image]

I added some OpenStreetMap background for reference.

Comment: But that is available since 2.16?

Comment: I have not tested older versions. Any reason to stuck to 2.8? On Windows, you can install multiple standalone versions in parallel.

Comment: Thanks alot for your effort. Thing is, I'm using version 2.8. Is this a feature thats available in newer versions?

Comment: Doenst seem to be available at 2.8, will try to use newer versions.

Comment: QGIS 2.16 gives me an error with the ssl certificate. How did you manage to bypass it? @AndreJ

Comment: The solution you gave is working. Because I'm working on some sort of server the ssl gave problems. Managed to resolve this using another external server. Thanks!