# Adding features from ArcGIS Online to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, arcgis-online, features, url

How can I **add features which provided by ArcGIS Online to QGIS map?**

I'd like to add feature like "USA Mean Temperature" with QGIS (2.18.3).
These useful features are easy to access when I use ArcGIS Online,
by doing "Add" -> "Search for Layers" -> Select "ArcGIS Online".

I guess "Layer" -> "Add Layer" -> "Add ArcGIS FeatureServer Layer" would be answer, but I'm not sure what URL I should use.

Could you tell me how I should do?

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your comment :)
I'm using 2.18.3.

Comment: just a reminder to mark this question answered

Answer (score 3):

You could find the URL here - [USA Mean Temperature](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4c6c0d9b6c294664afad07a326a37aca) services page provided by Esri.

They do provide a URL - https://landscape3.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Mean_Temperature/ImageServer

However, that URL leads you to a [ArcGIS Server REST API Login](https://landscape3.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/login?redirect=https%3A//landscape3.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Mean_Temperature/ImageServer) requesting a token to access. In addition there is a disclaimer:

> To login to Services Directory when your site is federated to a portal, you must enter a token.To acquire this token, go to https://www.arcgis.com and enter 'https://landscape3.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest' for the 'Webapp URL' parameter

On a separate note, this post [Adding ArcGIS Online Services to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202615/adding-arcgis-online-services-to-qgis) which shows the steps when accessing the ArcGIS REST services from a State agency in the US.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I couldn't figure out how to get a token. What does "enter 'https://landscape3.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest' for the 'Webapp URL' parameter" mean ? Do I need ArcGIS Desktop instead of ArcGIS Online ?

Comment: To get a token, you have to be an ArcGIS Online subsciber or part of the ArcGIS developer Network. Also the URL provided allows you to go to the page referenced, you will then see a message "To login to Services Directory when your site is federated to a portal, you must enter a token."

Comment: I logged in "ArcGIS Server REST API Login" with the token and tried to make Server connections with the URL, https://landscape3.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Mean_Temperature/ImageServer . But I got message "The query returned no layers.". What's wrong with me ? Even if I use client Id and password for Authentication, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Daichi, that's a good question. I suggest marking this question answered because the answer covers the original question. I recommend you create a new question with the current issue you are having and refer to this post in it s well. Hope that helps.