# Downloading data from ArcGIS Online?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-online

I am new to GIS. I am done making a map, using ArcGIS Online webmap. I have successfully installed QGIS 2.14, now I want to retrieve the map and layers from ArcGIS to be used in QGIS.

What steps should I take to download the map (data) from ArcGIS online?

Comment: The online map is a set of drawing rules to a huge archive of web-based data. Nothing about this is compatible with downloading data.  QGIS could easily access the same sources, but you'd likely need to regenerate your map from scratch. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202615/adding-arcgis-online-services-to-qgis

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @Vince:

> The online map is a set of drawing rules to a huge archive of
>   web-based data. Nothing about this is compatible with downloading
>   data.  QGIS could easily access the same sources, but you'd likely
>   need to regenerate your map from scratch. See
>   [Adding ArcGIS Online Services to QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202615)

Retrieving the map and layers from ArcGIS Online to view them in QGIS is a different topic to trying to download the data that is used by the map and layers on ArcGIS Online.  Reviewing [Difference between map layer and spatial dataset (e.g. feature class, shapefile)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26336) may help to understand that concept.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using ArcGIS Online, you can try [nextgis.com](http://nextgis.com/) - two directional data and styles intercharge.

Don't forget nice QGIS plugin - [NextGIS Connect](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nextgis_connect/) to achieve this functionality.

Additional documentation is [here](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/toc.html). Especially [here](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/ngqgis_connect.html#how-to-manage-data-with-desktop-app-nextgis-qgis).

[image]