# Adding ArcGIS Online Services to QGIS using MAC OSX?

Tags: qgis, mac, arcgis-rest-api

I just read [Adding ArcGIS Online Services to QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202615/adding-arcgis-online-services-to-qgis/253338#253338), but I do not have the options mentioned.

[image]

These are my options under Add Layer... Can't seem to find Add ArcGIS Map Server Layer. I'm running 2.18 on a Mac. There must be a difference between mac and pc versions? Is there a way to add ArcGIS Map Server Layer on a Mac??

Answer (score 0):

Same answer for QGIS 2.14 from [Adding ArcGIS Online Services to QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202615/adding-arcgis-online-services-to-qgis/253338#253338) works in QGIS 2.18 on OS X:

[image]

> 1. Install ArcGIS REST API Connector plugin. (a. Plugins - Manage and install plugins... b. Tab Settings. c. Mark checkbox Show also
>      experimental plugins. d. Tab All. e. Search for ArcGIS, select and
>      install ArcGIS REST API Connector plugin.)

[image]

> 2. Hit the ArcGIS icon in the Manage Layers Toolbar.

[image]

> 3. Enter the layer URL in field Layer URL. https://gis.ohiodnr.gov/arcgis/rest/services/OIT_Services/odnr_landbase/MapServer/2
>      Layernumber is important!

[image]

> 4. Put cursor in field Layer Name. If Layer URL is correct Layer Name will show up. Connect to add features to QGIS.

[image]