# Import public online map layer into QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, layers

I am collecting data about mobile phone coverage in my city. This is one of the *public maps* I found online. In the *source code of the website* owner I found the following ressource which is the visual layer of the LTE / 4G coverage:

https://netmap.vodafone.de/arcgis/rest/services/CoKart/netzabdeckung_mobilfunk/MapServer/export?dpi=300&transparent=true&format=png8&LANGUAGE=ger&layers=show%3A0%2C100%2C1&bbox=764766.9499904191%2C6664654.659215047%2C838146.497144092%2C6686018.808620726&bboxSR=3857&imageSR=3857&size=1920%2C800&f=image

I can play around with those parameters, I can call the image directly. But I can't *get it into my QGIS as a layer*.

Question: how do I have to set the "New WMS layer" source? Current approach is this which does not work.
https://netmap.vodafone.de/arcgis/rest/services/CoKart/netzabdeckung_mobilfunk/MapServer/

The QGIS version I am using is 2.14.21.

Comment: This isn't a WMS

Comment: Yes, that is what the answer below already pointed out.

Comment: I didn't read the answer, my WMS comment was a comment on the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works in 3.0, at least - add it using Data Source Manager as an '**ArcGIS Map Server**' (not WMS) using the following URL

> https://netmap.vodafone.de/arcgis/rest/services/CoKart/netzabdeckung_mobilfunk/MapServer/

You should now be able to see a list of layers when you click<kbd>Connect</kbd>. Select your layer from the list, click on <kbd>Add</kbd> and that should load it into QGIS.

[image]

(You might want to add a basemap layer e.g. OSM to better let you navigate to the area you want)

Comment: Thank you a lot! This seems quite easy. I am using QGIS 2.14, maybe it is easier to upgrade than to find a solution for 2.14.

Comment: see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/202633/55203), looks like it's built-in with 2.18 but done a slightly different way. I think a plugin was needed for 2.14 and earlier.

Comment: I installed QGIS version 3.2.0 and it works exactly like you described. Thank you!