# Downloading map as shapefile from ArcMap service?

Tags: arcmap

I am trying to export a polygon file (link is below) available on the ArcMap service as a shapefile.

Which tool I can use to do that?

https://services.arcgis.com/jIL9msH9OI208GCb/arcgis/rest/services/World_Lakes/FeatureServer

Comment: There's a world of difference between ArcMap and ArcGIS Online/ArcGIS Server services. There are scores of ways to convert a feature stream to a shapefile, using many different potential software packages. Please provide more information about the tool(s) you have available.

Comment: add arcgis online in qgis  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202615/adding-arcgis-online-services-to-qgis then right click and save features as shapefile.

Comment: I tried by using arcmap. I tried to export it however whichever tool I try is giving not responding error. Could anyone export it as shp? I want to clip and insert it into my basin. This seems very simple, but I spend all my day for that..